# Append specific entry to the end of a Queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to order a queryset by the CharField 'name', but I want to exclude the 'Other' entry and add it as a last option for the user to choose...

```
self.fields["acquisition"].queryset = AcquisitionChannel.objects.exclude(name = "Other").order_by('name')
```

The above is obviously not good because it excludes the 'Other'...

Could it be done in Django? or I must use Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To manually add objects to a QuerySet, try `_result_cache`:

```
other = AcquisitionChannel.objects.get(name="Other")    
objs = AcquisitionChannel.objects.exclude(name="Other").order_by("name")
len(objs) #hit the db to evaluate the queryset.
objs = objs._result_cache.append(other)
self.fields["acquisition"].queryset = objs
```

Comment: When I debug it looks like the queryset has all the items, but on the browser the 'Other' is missing. I have no idea why...

Comment: add this : objs = objs._result_cache.append(other) - updated my code to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple: add an `order` column that takes a special value using `extra()`:

```
self.fields["acquisition"].queryset = (
    AcquisitionChannel.objects
    .extra(select={'order': '(CASE name WHEN %s THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'},
           select_params=['Other'],
           order_by=['order', 'name']))
```

Using `params`, this method works on any DB (that supports `CASE`).

Comment: Didn't work... and anyway I don't want to force myself, or anyone else to use a specific DB... thanks for trying though

Comment: It worked pretty well here. Did it show an error message or something?

Comment: Databaes Error - column "Other" does not exist

Comment: Replaced quotes with `params`, to make the query not DB-specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's something like:

```
def get_choices():
    choices = AcquisitionChannel.objects.exclude(name = "Other").order_by('name').values_list('value_column', 'text_column')
    other = AcquisitionChannel.objects.filter(name = "Other").values_list('value_column', 'text_column')
    choices = list(choices)
    other = list(other)
    return choices + other
```

then:

```
acquisition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_choices())
```

Comment: yes, it does not work. how about ChoiceField and set choices to some values_list, then you can append.

Comment: But then it won't come from the database... so if next week a new value will be added the choice field won't be updated